# How can I remove unwanted CSS found in the parent theme?

Tags: 8, theming

I'm working on a sub-theme of Bootstrap Barrio, which includes a `table.css` stylesheet. I don't want this stylesheet from the parent theme to be included in my sub-theme.

How do I **eliminate** a CSS file from sub-theme's parent?

Comment: On a closer read, the title of the question didn't reflect the body of the question, which did actually ask how to remove the parent css file, so yes, thanks @leymannx. I just edited the title of the other question to correct the discrepancy and hopefully help others find the question.

Answer (score 5):

You can override it by adding a blank file with the same name in your theme (or you can add your own contents). Or, you can remove it altogether with libraries exclude: https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-theme#override-extend

Comment: Thanks, tried this but I must be doing something wrong. Please see [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/294400/99084).

Comment: Well, this is the answer to the current question that you asked. Why your implementation is not working is a new question (which you've correctly asked in a new thread). I don't have an answer to that one.

Comment: @Jaypan how would you override a contrib CSS file in your theme AND transform this CSS into a SCSS? What I am doing is the combination of overriding via blank .css file and then adding a SCSS component with the contrib CSS code in my theme and tune it to fit my needs using my variables, etc, but maybe there's a better approach.

Comment: I'm not the right person to ask, and that's probably a question that deserves a new thread as it's not really the same as the original question.